# php - array sort on the first dimension of a 2D array

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have this array structure

```
Array
(
    [xyz] => Array
        (
            [1] => 3
            [0] => s
        )

    [dds] => Array
        (
            [a] => 96
            [d] => 4

         )
...
)
```

How do I sort on the first dimension so that dds would be first. ksort does not work (at least for me).

TIA

edit
Here is my simple code.  I read a serialized 2D array file into a variable, and do a sort on it, nothing complicated, ksort works on my 1D array without a problem.  If I comment out the ksort line, then it runs without errors.

```
$inputfile = "xxx/result.txt";    
$builta = file_get_contents($inputfile);
$built =unserialize($builta);
    $size = sizeof($built);
    echo $size;

    echo "<br><pre>";
    print_r ($built);
    echo "</pre>";

    ksort($built);

    echo "<br><pre>";
    print_r ($built);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Nothing complicated.

Update: after encountering more errors from dealing with large arrays, it appeared that the problem with ksort was due to not having enough memory to sort large arrays.  The solution offered by tpaksu is a great workaround.

Comment: Let's be explicit here: You're using the ksort function wrong. Look into the manual, see how it works, have a nice time. It's easy when you know how, it's hard if you don't learn how. To give you an easy start: ksort in the manual is here: http://php.net/ksort. Always read about the parameters, the return type and see the example(s) given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your array's name is $my_array; then you can use something like this:

```
<?php
$my_array = array(z => array(p=>1,gf=>"d"),v=>array(l=>"m",fr=>"3"));
var_dump($my_array);

$sorted_keys = array_keys($my_array);
sort($sorted_keys,SORT_STRING);
$new_array = array();

var_dump($sorted_keys);

foreach($sorted_keys as $key){
    $new_array[$key] = $my_array[$key];
}

var_dump($new_array);

?>
```

But yes ksort would be better and simpler.

Edit : Sorry my bad. using sort as inline function was a mistake. Here's the updated,tested and working code.

Comment: Thanks tpaksu, but this does not work for me either, it errors out as Invalid argument supplied for foreach() .  Yes, I made sure the variable names are correct.

Comment: thanks for your time, the code works great, but it does consume a ton of memory (for my large 2D array).

Comment: instead of assigning the old array to a new array, you might just use the $sorted_keys when calling your old array. it'll be much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php).

```
ksort($array);
```

Comment: Hi Dogbert, that does not work, I just tried it before I asked.

Comment: My array is $xxx, then I have $xxx = ksort($xxx);

Comment: ksort modifies in-place, don't assign its result back to `$xxx`.

Comment: @Interrobang, I tried assigning another var to ksort result, but it does not work, ksort seems to destroy the 2nd dimension.

Comment: @Jamex `ksort` works on a *reference* of the array, the return value is just a boolean. You should just do `$array = array(...); ksort($array);`, meaning you discard the return value. The function modifies the array directly.

Comment: @AnotherCode, thanks, ksort works just fine for my 1D arrays, I just tested them, but for some reasons, ksort is messing up my 2D array.  You seem to lead me in the right track because when I try print_r the array after ksort, it gives an error expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in...

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP function **`uksort()`**, that sorts the array based on the keys. But you have to build your own comparison function.
 
You cane get the documentation of this function [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php)